# Не меняется цвет у компонента JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Итак. Есть класс Window(наследник JFrame), у него такой менеджер компоновки:

```
this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
```

Табличный то бишь, код сгенерирован IDE(Eclipse). Далее, я создал класс Panel(наследник JPanel):

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{

    private LinkedList<Figure> figures;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc_panel;

    public Panel(int gridheight, Insets insets, int gridx, int gridy) {
        super();
        gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc_panel.insets = insets;
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = gridx;
        gbc_panel.gridy = gridy;
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 4));
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    GridBagConstraints GetGridBagConstraints() {
        return this.gbc_panel;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Dimension dim = getSize(); // размер панели
        Image buf = createImage(dim.width, dim.height); // буфер
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) buf.getGraphics(); // теневой буфер

        Oval o = new Oval(20, 20, 190, 190);
        o.DrawPolygon(g2);

        g.drawImage(buf, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

И в классе Window создаю эту панельку:

```
    MainPanelDraw = new Panel(5, new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5) ,5, 1);
    MainPanelDraw.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.add(MainPanelDraw, 
    MainPanelDraw.GetGridBagConstraints());
```

Дак вот, все прекрасно работает, фигура отрисовывается, перерисовывается - но Panel не меняет свой цвет на белый. Прозрачность я отключил. В чем моя беда? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь аннотацию @Override и вызови суперкласс:

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: Если в классе Panel, то безрезультатно.

Comment: Да в классе Panel. Я проверил - должно работать. У тебя с инициализацией непонятка. Должно быть как-то так: Panel panel = new Panel(...);

Comment: Просто в классе Window есть приватный член: private Panel MainPanelDraw;
Поэтому и такая инициализация. Он мне нужен просто.

Comment: Убери(закомментируй)  пока все в методе paintComponent. Оставь только код, который я указал в ответе.

Comment: Сделал. Панель стала совсем маленькой, может ей хотя бы размеры задать?

Comment: не в конструкторе, а в paintComponent, я сначала не так написал...

Comment: Да, фон обновляется на белый. Но как же быть с отрисовкой примитивов?

Comment: У меня отрисовываются, только имидж не пробовал. Раскомментируй код отрисовки овала.

Comment: Как-то странно. Отрисовал овал напрямую, и все работает. Почему нет проблем с мерцанием..или в PaintComponent теневой буфер уже включен?

Comment: Это уже новый вопрос. Я на изначальный вроде ответил...